# Как кликнуть по кнопке на форме и получить новый результат с помощью Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Занимаюсь небольшим сбором информации о ссылках на сайте. Требуется нажать на кнопку "Показать всё" и получить дополнительную информацию. Немного не понимаю как это сделать? Пробовал код ниже: элемент находится, вроде происходит нажатие, но ничего не изменяется...

```
import bs4
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


opts = Options()
opts.headless = True
browser = Chrome(options=opts)

browser.get('https://dominfo.ru/uk/region/belgorodskaya-oblast/belgorod')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div').click()

por = browser.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(por, 'html.parser')

qwe = []
for a_tag in soup.findAll(class_="a a_blue"):
    href = a_tag.attrs.get("href")
    qwe.append(href)

    print(href)
    print(len(qwe))

browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надо просто немного подождать, пока эелементы загрузятся

```
import time

from selenium.webdriver import Firefox


browser = Firefox()


try:
    browser.get('https://dominfo.ru/uk/region/belgorodskaya-oblast/belgorod')
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    for element in browser.find_elements_by_class_name("a_blue"):
        print(element.get_attribute("href"))
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{type(e).__name__}{getattr(e, 'args', None)}")
finally:
    browser.quit()
```